# WebView over ImageView Android

Tags: html, android-layout, android-webview, android-imageview

I have read multiple posts for solutions on how to display a WebView over an ImageView.  Here is what I tried last and it still doesn't work:

```
 mPhotoWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
 mPhotoWebView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp" >

    <com.example.android.views.MyImageView
        android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/photoWebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
```

html style:

```
body 
{
    background:transparent;
    background-color: rgba(10,10,10,0.5);
}
```

This code needs to run on 4.2.2.  What I am trying to accomplish, is the webview has animation code done in html5 and the imageView is a background image that the animations need to show over.

Any ideas?

Comment: I finally got this working.  See below answer.

Answer (score 0):

I must have missed this combination before.  My final solution, that works is:

Do not set background color to webView in the code.

```
    body 
    {
        background:transparent;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: rgba(10,10,10,0.5);
    }
```

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp" >

    <com.accuweather.android.views.MyImageView
        android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/photoWebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layerType="software"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
```

Key here is the software layerType.  I am using a fragment of which one activity handles many, so I couldn't do this in the manifest.  Therefore I did so in the xml.